# No module named 'model'

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import numpy as np
import random
import json

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize, stem
from model import NeuralNet
```

i keep trying to `pip install NeuralNet` but I keep getting

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

I have Neuralnet successfully installed on my pc, and I have have tried what you said I should try and its still not working, can I send you the project on linkedin so you would check it out

Comment: have you verified the installation location for 'model'?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to import neuralnet by itself:

```python
import neuralnet
```

or import model from neuralnet:

```python
from neuralnet import model
```

Since model seems to be a [part of the NeuralNet module](https://github.com/justanhduc/neuralnet/tree/master/neuralnet) rather than the other way around.

Comment: I have Neuralnet successfully installed on my pc, and I have have tried what you said I should try and its still not working, can I send you the project on linkedin so you would check it out

Comment: Could you edit your original question to show what you tried and add the error message you're getting?

Comment: don't import as `nn` as this is already used for `torch.nn`

Comment: good point, DerekG, I edited the question. I only suggested that since they suggest it in the documentation.